# CSS animate remove from DOM

Tags: css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="products-container">
    {foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
  <div class="product"     data-id-product="{$product.id_product}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute}">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have a javascript that can remove any div `.product`.
Is there a way to fade the deleted div out of the DOM to the right and animate the other divs 'moving up to the free space'?

Comment: You can animate the `opacity` to `0`, then with a delay the `height` to `0` as well in combination with `overflow: hidden`. Finally on `transitionend` you remove the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple example

```js
let btt = document.querySelector('button');
let products_cnt = document.querySelector('.products');
let products  = document.querySelectorAll('.product');

products[0].addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  [...products].forEach((p) => p.parentNode.removeChild(p))
});

btt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  products_cnt.classList.add('products--delete');
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px #9bc solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #69A;
  font: 1em system-ui;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  cursor: pointer; }

.products {
  overflow-x: hidden; }

.product {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 1.5s 0s, opacity 1.25s 0s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.products--delete .product {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Remove product/s</button>

<section class="products">
  <div>Not a product</div>
  <div class="product">Product</div>
  <div class="product">Product</div>
  <div>Not a product</div>
  <div class="product">Product</div>
  <div>Not a product</div>
</section>
```

---

Explanation: when you click the button the class `.products--delete` is added to the `.products_container` element: this starts a CSS transition over the `.product` elements.

Finally, when the `transitionend` event occurs on a single product element just remove from the DOM all products.

Answer (score 5):

You can use css transitions in your CSS. The part of removing may be different for you. Please click the product to remove it.

```js
let productsRy = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product"));


productsRy.forEach((p,i)=>{
  p.style.top = i * (3 + 1) * 16 +"px";
  p.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  container.removeChild(p);
  productsRy = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product"));
  productsRy.forEach((p1,i1)=>{p1.style.top = i1 * (3 + 1) * 16 +"px";})
})
  
  
})
```

```css
.products-container{position:relative;}

.product{
  position:absolute;
  padding:1em; 
  margin:.5em;
  height:3em;
  outline:1px solid; width:200px;
  height:auto;
  transition: all 1s;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="products-container" id="container">
  <div class="product"  data-id-product="a" data-id-product-attribute="a">
  product a
  </div>
    <div class="product"  data-id-product="b" data-id-product-attribute="b">
  product b
  </div>
    <div class="product"  data-id-product="c" data-id-product-attribute="c">
  product c
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS really doesn't have the ability to modify an object in the same manner as JavaScript. you can do this easily.

```
$(".product").fadeTo("slow", 0.00, function(){
    $(this).slideUp("slow", function() {
         $(this).remove();
    });
});
```